# Django self.model.DoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, django-orm, uuid

I have a user with a field set as None:

```
None|Default User|07/07/2023
```

However, Django for some reason does not see it:

```
queryset=Q(id=UUID(User.objects.get(user_id=None)
...
raise self.model.DoesNotExist(pages.models.User.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist
```

The closing parentheses are present.

Setting the default field as another UUID present in the database as well isn't of any help. I am trying to run the migrations.

My models:

```
class User(models.Model):

"""
A class presenting user who can view lessons and have access to them
"""

user_id = models.UUIDField(
    primary_key=True,
    default=uuid.uuid4,
    editable=False,
    null=True
    )
name = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='Name')
date_of_registration = models.TimeField(default=timezone.now)

def __str__(self):
    return self.id
```

Setting the default to a present `user_id` doesn't help as well. Similar questions on stackoverflow were left without answers, no information about this particular problem in the Internet was found. What additional information should I provide?

Comment: What if you use `User.objects.get(user_id='None')`?

Comment: I am sure django has warned you that primary keys cannot be nullable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UUID is not `NULL`, so `user_id=None` will not work, it is the string `None`, so you retrieve this with:

```
User.objects.get(user_id='None')
```

A UUID is on most databases just a `CharField` that stores the UUID as a string, so it will call `str(…)` on it, and apparently it did that on the `None` object.

Comment: Why setting it to another present UUID `27451070-f784-46fb-af02-af98cc47f393|Default User|07/07/2023` doesn't help? The query: `User.objects.get(user_id='27451070-f784-46fb-af02-af98cc47f393'`

Comment: Thanks for the information provided, though. It successfully returned the user with `'None'`, though it's not a valid UUID and the rest failed.

Comment: @Ani: what do you mean with "the rest failed"?

Comment: `django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“None” is not a valid UUID.']`
@WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @Ani: well you can not use that in a form, since then validators will indeed run and raise that error. You thus should *omit* that record: a NULLable primary key is *not* a good idea.

Comment: Done, still doesn't find the record with a present primary key that is not NULL

Comment: @Ani: but none of the records are `NULL`, all records are non-NULL strings, one with `None`. What if you use `User.objects.filter(user_id=UUID('27451070-f784-46fb-af02-af98cc47f393'))`, exactly what does happen?

Comment: Exactly what I've described above: it doesn't find the record. Perhaps I should have formulated it clearly :(

Answer (score 0):

```
from uuid import UUID

try:
    user_uuid = UUID("your_uuid_here")  # Replace "your_uuid_here" with the actual UUID
    user = User.objects.get(user_id=user_uuid)
except User.DoesNotExist:
    # Handle the case where the user doesn't exist
    user = None  # Or any other appropriate action
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).